# TcpClient C# different behavior from different clients

Tags: c#, tcpclient, handshake

I have a server which uses `TcpClient.AcceptTcpClient()` to accept clients.
I also have a client which also uses C# TcpClient like this:

```
 var client = new TcpClient();
 client.connect(ip, port);
```

This is working as it should, but when I try to connect to my server with the tcp_socket_send from kontiki (C-code), it shows unwanted behavior. It looks like when it sends a message, it sends a SYN. Then the server returns SYN-ACK, so that seems fine. When the client then sends the actual message, the server has accepted it as a new TcpClient.

I hope I made my question clear enough, otherwise ask away.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've isolated the problem, but I do not have the answer yet. 
The problem is that the way kontiki sends data is SYN, then PSH. The way my C# tcpclient sends data is directly PSH. It leaves the SYN. The problem is (It think) that the SYN closes my previous connection somehow.

Comment: How you get sure about new TCP Client accepted in server side. Please show some code snippest of TCP server. There is a IPEndPoint property of socket (use only the IP address of the IPEndPoint). you can use it in server side to check from which end your message came form.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Before I send some snippets. Please check out my edit.

Comment: Also make sure not to create new TcpClient() in client side when you sending second part of your message to TCP server form TCP client because it will create new IPEndPoint and your TCP server assume it as different Client. Hope this help.